# How to read post request in node using different ports in cloud 9

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, http-post, cloud9-ide

Okay, so I'm currently making an ionic app in cloud9. I've come to the point where I have to send a post request to my node.js server. Here's my problem:

When I post the data from my controller in angular and then console.log the data in my server.js my data seems missing

server.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var headers = request.headers;
  var method = request.method;
  var url = request.url;
  var body = [];
  request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', function(chunk) {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

  console.log(method);
  console.log(request.data);
  console.log("hi");
  });
}).listen(8081, process.env.IP); // Activates this server, listening on port 8081.
```

server-side console:

```
POST
undefined
hi
```

client-side:

```
 $http({
     method  : 'POST',
     url     : 'https://face-find-splacorn.c9users.io:8081',
     data    : "blah", //forms user object
     headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
 })
```

Also, I'm getting this error on the client side:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://face-find-splacorn.c9users.io:8081/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://face-find-splacorn.c9users.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

(since it might be considered as a separate domain and will be declared unsafe^)

But at the end of the day, my posts requests still gets sent through because my server outputs the data that it knows.

I'm using ionic in cloud 9 so I need to run the server.js on a different port so the two "servers" won't conflict each other

But where is my post data? I would be very grateful if someone looked over my code and thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: A few questions: 1) Have you made your application url public? 2) if you replace HTTPS with HTTP in your POST request, does that help?

Comment: The url is public and putting HTTP instead of HTTPS will send an error saying that the connection was not secure. So HTTPS must be used in the POST request.

Comment: I think you can still try HTTP instead of HTTPS if you access your main app using HTTP too. Can you give that a try and see? I just want to figure out if the issue is due to HTTPS on that port, or something else